# Customised Campaign - URL Builder - not working

Tags: google-analytics

Campaigns that where correctly tracked last week as:

source: LinkedIn
medium: cpc
are now not working properly without any change.

Taking the Analytics ID from a new lead coming from this source/medium today, it can be seen as coming from (direct) / (none).

No changes were made to the URL. 
The only change made to the landing page is the insertion of a Remarketing tag.

Any ideas of where the problem might be?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google Analytics campaign builder and is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/